# Циклический связанный список на Rust

Tags: rust

Хочу написать циклический односвязный список. Но проблема в том что при создании первый элемент должен ссылаться на сам себя. я вроде бы слышал что для этого нужно обернуть в `Pin`. но это не помогло. как это можно реализовать?

```rust
struct node {
    data:i32,
    next: Option<Pin<Box<node>>>
}

struct List {
    frist: Box<node>,
    last: Box<node>
}

fn create_list(data:i32) {
    let mut node = Box::new(node{ data, next: None });
    let pin = Pin::new(node);
    node.next = Some(pin);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
error[E0382]: assign to part of moved value: `*node`

     let mut node = Box::new(node { data, next: None });
         -------- move occurs because `node` has type `std::boxed::Box<node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
     let pin = Pin::new(node);
                        ---- value moved here
     node.next = Some(pin);
     ^^^^^^^^^ value partially assigned here after move
```

Comment: Связанные списки в *Rust* — это **боль.**  Всегда была и всегда будет.  Почитайте вот тут: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Comment: Может вам всетаки попробовать safe Arc, Rc (счетчики ссылок). То что вам ниже предлагают вариант из unsafe это конечно хорошо, но вы нагородите себе дыр.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html

Answer (score 0):

Проблема всех связных списков в Rust, кроме простейшего односвязного - в том, что отношение владения между элементами неопределено. Элементами владеет список целиком, но у него нет указателя на каждый элемент списка - потому стандартный контейнер для элемента и не выбрать.

Контейнером должен стать список целиком, и единственный нормальный способ такой контейнер сделать - это unsafe и сырые указатели:

```rust
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: *mut Self,
}

struct List<T> {
    first: *mut Node<T>
}

fn create_list<T>(data: T) -> List<T> {
    unsafe {
        let node = Node { data, next: std::ptr::null_mut() };
        let node_ptr = Box::into_raw(Box::new(node));
        (*node_ptr).next = node_ptr;
        List { first: node_ptr }
    }
}
```

И не забудьте написать деструктор для списка:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for List<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let head = self.first;
            if head.is_null() { return; }

            let mut node = head;
            loop {
                let next = (*node).next;
                Box::from_raw(node);
                node = next;
                if node == head { break; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код я не запускал, так что прошу относиться к нему как к черновику, и исправить ошибки если таковые будут замечены.

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать `Rc` или `Arc` для `next`. Тогда можно обойтись без unsafe и реализации Drop, ценой скорости работы и занимаемым в памяти местом (из-за добавленного счётчика ссылок)

Comment: @kstep использовать `Rc` для заведомо циклического списка нет ни малейшего смысла

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Weak.html

Comment: @kstep вы не можете сделать в циклическом односвязном списке часть связей через Rc, а часть через Weak. В конце концов, у вас всего одно поле в узле. Попробуйте не кидаться ссылками на документацию, а написать рабочий код, если не понимаете о чём я.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте клонировать или передать по ссылке.

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    data:i32,
    next:Option<Pin<Box<Node>>>
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct List {
    frist: Box<Node>,
    last: Box<Node>
}

fn create_list(data:i32) {
    let mut node = Box::new(Node{data,next: None});
    let a = node.clone();
    node.next = Some(Pin::new(a));
}

fn main () {

create_list(4);

}
```

Comment: Вот только `node.next` должно указывать на `node`, а не на его копию. Иначе это уже не циклический список из одного элемента, а какая-то ерунда.